# Coldfusion: What are security issues that can occur if I allow users to upload .css and .js files to my site

Tags: coldfusion

I want users to upload their themes containing .css, .js files to my server in zip format, Once they will upload the application will unzip it and the user will be able to see the theme at mysite.com/themes/user/. I want to know what security issues can occur if I allow user to upload .css and js files to my server. Can the malicious code redirect the site or do DOS service attack or change the dynamic aspects on my site. Scanning the files for malicious code before unzipping seems impractical. What safeguards should I take.

Comment: If you aren't executing any of the code server-side, the only issues you may have are what the malicious code does client-side. For example, it could create a recursive js function that repeatedly queries your server with little to no delay, thus causing legitimate users of your site to unknowingly attack your server. Or it could inject code that tracks what forms the user fills out, such as login forms. Or it could read the user's cookie information and send it to a 3rd party, thus letting the 3rd party gain access to that user's session. css files can of course mangle your site layout.

Comment: Yes these are some concerns that is worrying me. How do the theme hosting sites accept themes from users and host them on their site?. Do they have man-in-the-middle that checks and validates the themes for flaws before uploading to their site. This kind of thing would be a deal breaker for me

Comment: There are several ways to check for malicious code, but I doubt any of them are perfect. Regex tests are difficult with obfuscation, human tests can fail due to human mistakes, etc. best to just avoid it, or to run the code in a sandbox that limits the code's functionality.

Answer (score 4):

1. First and foremost, don't unzip them into a public "temp" folder while you're doing whatever else you're going to do with them.
2. There's no telling what that ZIP file will actually contain.
3. There's no telling what those JS files will try to do to your site.

You should read what [Samy did to MySpace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samy_%28computer_worm%29) before you implement this functionality. ([A breakdown of the attack.](http://betanews.com/2005/10/13/cross-site-scripting-worm-hits-myspace/))